# Requested dump when trying to call await in Xamarin Forms with TTS

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, async-await, text-to-speech

I have used Xamarin.Essentials TTS and everything worked fine, but later configuring Geolocation I got some errors so after a few hours of debugging I got rid of all errors, but now when I run it the TTS doesn't work properly. When I run app it stucks at await GetLocalesAsync method, and after few seconds I got requested dump for tid.
When I set breakpoint and go line by line it automatically stops the program when gets to await.

```
if (_locales.Count == 0 || refreshKey)
            {
                IEnumerable<Locale> locales = await TextToSpeech.GetLocalesAsync();
                IEnumerator<Locale> localesEnumerator = locales.GetEnumerator();

                while (localesEnumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    _locales.Add(localesEnumerator.Current);
                }
            }
```

Do I need any permissions?
Is it possible that I just changes some version of Android or something similar and that's why it doesn't work now?

Comment: Did you change your TargetFramework?

Comment: It's .NET Standard 2.1 could have been 2.0 before

Comment: For Android i mean...

Comment: Yes, but after then it worked, and stopped after changing permissions, finally started working again, no clue why, I cleaned everything and restarted everything and works now

Comment: That is great...